# x86-64 Assembly to C

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x86-64

I tried translating this into C, but I'm stuck at the displacement of the memory address (`%rdi`):

```
program:
  movq  (%rdi), %rax
  testq %rax, %rax
  je L1
  addq  $8, %rdi
  movq  %rax, %rdx
L3:
  cmpq  %rdx, %rax
  cmovl %rdx, %rax
  addq  $8, %rdi
  movq  -8(%rdi), %rdx
  testq %rdx, %rdx
  jne L3
L1:
  ret
```

I've come up with following so far:

```c
int func(int *x){
    int ret = *x;
    if(ret != 0){
        x+=8; //is this true?
        y = ret;
        while(y!=0){
            if(ret<y){
                ret = y;
            }
            y=?? //What should this say?
        }
    }
    return ret;
```

Possible solution (waiting for someone to confirm):

```
int func(int *x){
  int ret = *x;
  if(ret!=0){
    ++x;
    int y = ret;
    while(y != 0){
      if(ret < y){
        ret = y;
      }
      ++x;
      y = x[-1];
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Also, I don't suppose you have it in an understandable format, ie.  not AT&T?

Comment: @MartinJames the assembly *is* in AT&T syntax (which I really dislike to a point where I wish it would cease to exist, but I don't see anything wrong about the code in question, looks as valid AT&T).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   x+=8; //is this true?
```

No. `x` is `int *`, and on your current target platform `int` is 64 bit wide, which is 8 bytes. In assembly you have raw pointer to bytes, as memory is addressable by bytes, so the `add rdi,8` is in C like `x = (int*)(((int8_t*)x)+8);` which can be shortened to `++x;`

And if `movq  (%rdi), %rdx` is `rdx = x[0]; // or " = *x;"`, then `movq  -8(%rdi), %rdx` is `rdx = x[-1];`

The remaining C part looks unfinished.

Warning, spoiler is following!

> it will search through the `x` array until zero value is found (terminator), and keep updating `ret` with smallest value found.

And it looks like my spoiler was wrong, the compare is probably the other way. Just to make sure, run both original asm in debugger, and your C, to see if they do the same thing. Also watching assembly in debugger single-stepping over instructions, checking how values in registers evolve, is often lot more descriptive and visual, than any long discussion. :) Sorry for not being sure, but the AT&T syntax is driving me nuts.

BTW, my "C" translation would look probably like this (let's say the asm is searching for "max" value in array, not "min" (I'm still only ~90% sure)):

```
int64_t func(int64_t *x) {
    if (0 == *x) return 0;
    int64_t ret = *x;
    do {
        if (ret < *x) ret = *x;
        ++x;
    } while (0 != *x);
    return ret;
}
```

Which gets [translated by gcc v7.2](https://godbolt.org/g/ByUeMW) as (I had to change the `int` to `int64_t` to have 64b `int`):

```
func(long*):
  movq (%rdi), %rax
  testq %rax, %rax
  je .L1
  movq %rax, %rdx
.L3:
  cmpq %rdx, %rax
  cmovl %rdx, %rax
  addq $8, %rdi
  movq (%rdi), %rdx
  testq %rdx, %rdx
  jne .L3
.L1:
  rep ret
```

Which is almost identical to original assembly.

Comment: Thanks! That clarifies a lot - however, i'm not sure what i miss otherwise in the translation? What is unfinished aside from the y = ? I couldn't put together the last parts :/

Comment: @AndersLassen you must keep reading further members of array `x` into something (`y`), and keep updating minimal value, yet to not overwrite it with the terminating zero (that's maybe the reason of a bit convoluted asm code logic advancing pointer ahead and then just fetching the value from it's previous position, or who knows why, compilers are complex beasts). ... try to write it few more times in C, even when you half-way figure out it will not work, but try to finish all steps, and then refactoring it again until it is correct, that will help you to overcome some "stuck" moments.

Comment: After few rounds of refactoring and cleaning up you will probably end with something quite short and elegant.

Comment: I think i refined it now - have a look! :)

Comment: Maybe it should be ret > y instead?

Comment: @AndersLassen Indeed, it's sort of easy to run your C... at the moment it is returning largest value (your first possible solution proposal). `cmovl` means "conditional move when *less* flags are true", and the SF+OF (flags which are used to decide whether "less" condition is true = (SF <> OF)) contains value from `cmpq  %rdx, %rax`, which is in Intel syntax `cmp rax,rdx`, which is `(ret - y)`, so "less" will be set when `ret < y` ...  .... I'm proving myself wrong. I can't ever get the AT&T `cmp` right, would you mind simply use debugger and see yourself which is which? Looks like `max` func.

Comment: Thanks it explains a lot! Yeah, i really get confused about the syntax as well.. I think of the cmpq and cmovl instructions as: `ret-y < 0 <=> ret < y `. And if that is the case, `ret = y`. Reasonable?

Comment: @AndersLassen Yes, at the moment I think you are correct, but if this would be my task, I would run both asm and C in debugger to make 100% sure.

Comment: `int` is 32 bits on all x86-64 compilers I'm aware of. The datatype here should probably be `int64_t`.

Comment: @interjay yes, I think maybe the windows64 may have `int` as 64b, but I'm not sure, haven't seen MS windows for a decade. I had to fix my C source to `int64_t` for testing purposes too, to get similar assembly to original.

Comment: On 64-bit Windows, even `long` is 32 bits.